# Limit for linear first order ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given
$$\frac{dx}{dt}+a(t)x(t)=f(t)$$ such that $a(t), f(t)$ are continuous and $$0<c\leq a(t)$$. If $$\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t)=0$$, prove that $$\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) =0$$ for every solution.

Solutions are
$$x(t) = e^{-\int_{}^{}a(t) dt}c+e^{-\int a(t) dt}\int_{}^{}e^{\int a(t) dt}f(t) dt]$$

For the first term of the sum, given $$0<c \leq a(t) \rightarrow e^{-\int a(t) dt}\leq e^{-\int c dt}$$ its limit is zero for $ t \to \infty$. But I'm unsure how to prove it for the second part of the sum. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the solution as
$$ x(t)=\exp\bigg[-\int_0^ta(\tau)d\tau\bigg]x(0)+\exp\bigg[-\int_0^ta(s)ds\bigg]\int_0^t\exp\bigg[\int_0^sa(\tau)d\tau\bigg]f(s)ds. $$
Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Using $a(t)>c>0$, one has that $\exists t_0>0$
$$ t\ge t_0\Rightarrow\bigg|\exp\bigg[-\int_0^ta(\tau)d\tau\bigg]x(0)\bigg|\le\exp(-ct)|x_0|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4} \tag{1} $$
and
$$ t\ge t_0\Rightarrow\exp(-ct)\int_0^{t_1}\exp\bigg[\int_0^sa(\tau)d\tau\bigg]|f(s)|ds <\frac{\varepsilon}{4} \tag{2} $$
Since $f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$, one has that $\exists t_1>0$ such that
$$ t\ge t_1\Rightarrow|f(t)|<c\varepsilon/2. $$
So for $t>t_0$,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\exp\bigg[-\int_0^ta(s)ds\bigg]\int_0^t\exp\bigg[\int_0^sa(\tau)d\tau\bigg]f(s)ds\bigg| \\
&=&\exp\bigg[-\int_0^ta(s)ds\bigg]\bigg[\int_0^{t_1}\exp\bigg[\int_0^sa(\tau)d\tau\bigg]f(s)ds +\int_{t_1}^t\exp\bigg[\int_0^sa(\tau)d\tau\bigg]f(s)ds\bigg]\\
&\le& \frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\int_{t_1}^t\exp\bigg[-\int_s^ta(\tau)d\tau\bigg]|f(s)|ds\\
&\le&\frac{\varepsilon}{4} +\int_{t_1}^t\exp(-c(t-s))|f(s)|ds\\
&\le&\frac{\varepsilon}{4} +\frac12c\varepsilon\int_{t_1}^t\exp(-c(t-s))ds\\
&\le&\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}(1-\exp(c(t_1-t)))\\
&\le&\frac{\varepsilon}{4} +\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\frac{3\varepsilon}4. \tag3
\end{eqnarray}
So one has that from (1), (2) and (3),
$$ t\ge t_2\Rightarrow|x(t)|\le \varepsilon $$
where $t_2=\max\{t_0,t_1\}$; namely
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0. $$